# Convert period_range to list of string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this

```
>>> start
'1905'
>>> end
'2003'
>>> p = pd.period_range(pd.to_datetime(start, format="%y%m"), pd.to_datetime(end, format="%y%m"), freq='M')
>>> p
PeriodIndex(['2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10',
             '2019-11', '2019-12', '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

I want to convert p to list of string which will contain period as

```
>>> p
['1905', '1906', '1907', '1908', '1909', '1910', '1911', '1912', '2001', '2002', '2003']
```

Format of string matters, it should be in same format as shown in eg('yymm')
Can someone help me in achieving this cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`PeriodIndex.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html) with `'%y%m'` to indicate "YYMM" format:

```
p.strftime('%y%m')
# Index(['1905', '1906', '1907', '1908', '1909', '1910', '1911', '1912', '2001',
#        '2002', '2003'],
#       dtype='object')
```